# Why does NextJS add @types/node to dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I built a project with NextJS and found that

```
"@types/node": "20.1.2",
"@types/react": "18.2.6",
"@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
"autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
"eslint": "8.40.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.4.1",
```

are located in dependencies by default, not devDependencies. Why does this happen and should I manually reinstall these packages using --save-dev?

Comment: You can safely move them (just edit package.json), some people don't seem to care about the distinction (by default all deps are installed regardless so it rarely breaks things). Create React App also have their @types in deps